# remove the max value in a "survfit" function in R

Tags: r

So I made a list, which contains several functions (Survfit() functions).

The survfit function within this list has "survfit" as class

The survfit function contains columns like: $time.

So now we have:

```
the_list[[i]]$function$time
```

**I want to remove a row which contains the maximum value of time and want to keep the class."

I can get the max %time value like this:

```
the_list[[i]]$function$time %>% max()
```

Comment: solution <- the_list[the_list[[i]]$function$time != the_list[[i]]$function$time %>% max()]

It works, because it returns TRUE and FALSE and only stores the TRUE.

Comment: ps. the functions was actually a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

solution <- the_list[the_list[[i]]$function$time != the_list[[i]]$function$time %>% max()] It works, because it returns TRUE and FALSE and only stores the TRUE.

ps. the functions was actually a dataframe –

KR ARNAND